# How to swap two words in a Microsoft Word document?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a very long file which refers certain persons as Petitioners and certain persons as Respondents. I want to swap these two words so that the Petitioner is changed to Respondent, and vice versa.
Can this be done automatically?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Use a third word that does not occur in your text.
e.g.

- change (find and replace) all 'Petitioner' to 'PetitionerXX',
- then change all 'Respondent' to 'Petitioner',
- and finally change all 'PetitionerXX' to 'Respondent'.

Comment: I would use something even more unique than appending a couple of XX, eg. "[QWERTYIUIO]". And **always review the changes performed**. Sometimes unexpected words arise. If you were changing "petition" to "response", you wouldn't want the _petitioner_ to become the _responseer_. Whereas you probably do want _petitioners_ to become _repondents_.

Comment: Also put the unique appending text at the beginning and end of the word to avoid the above stated issue.

Comment: @Ángel if one feels really paranoid, it's a good idea to generate a one-time-use UUID as something truly unique :)

Comment: and use the "match whole word" and "case sensitive" options carefully. Furthermore, there may be multiple grammatical cases that need to be considered: Petitioners, petitioner's, petitioners', petitioner, hyphenated compounds like "petitioner-caused" etc. Some versions of Word have a tick box for this in the replace dialog, I've no idea how sophisticated that is.